# Retrieve IoT Hub connection string by policy

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I've been retrieving the connection string for the `iothubowner` policy based on it being the first one in the key list when the IoT Hub is created:

```
"value": "[concat('HostName=', reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Devices/IoTHubs', parameters('iotHubName')), providers('Microsoft.Devices', 'IoTHubs').apiVersions[0]).hostName, ';SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Devices/IotHubs', parameters('iotHubName')), providers('Microsoft.Devices', 'IoTHubs').apiVersions[0]).value[0].primaryKey)]"
```

Is there some way to retrieve a connection string for a specific policy without having to rely on ordering?